# PHP: DOMDocument - attributes with a colon in it?

Tags: php, svg, attributes, namespaces, domdocument

I'm using DOMDocument to parse an XML  (SVG).

Some nodes have attributes with a colon in it, like :

```
<svg 
   id="svg2"
   width="1000"
   height="1000"
   sodipodi:version="0.32"
   inkscape:version="0.48.1 "
   ...
>
```

But when I do :

```
$node= DOMDocument->documentElement;
foreach($node->childNodes as $key=>$childnode) {
  foreach($childnode->attributes as $attribute) {
    echo $attribute->name."\n";
  }
}
```

the attributes with a : are printed without the first part (namespace)

How do I get the namespace for that attribute when iterating through the attributes like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from OP's comment, `nodeName` from [DOMNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php).

```
$node= DOMDocument->documentElement;
foreach($node->childNodes as $key=>$childnode) {
  foreach($childnode->attributes as $attribute) {
    echo $attribute->nodeName."\n";
  }
}
```

Original Answer:

How about `prefix` from [DOMNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)?

```
$node= DOMDocument->documentElement;
foreach($node->childNodes as $key=>$childnode) {
  foreach($childnode->attributes as $attribute) {
    echo $attribute->prefix.":".$attribute->name."\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanx, already found the other properties of the $attribute variable (DOMNode). I use $attribute->nodeName now , which returns the entire attribute name whether it has a namespace or not...

Comment: Great! Updated answer with your results for archiving.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to work with namespaces (which is what the colon indicates) explicitly when you use `DOMDocument`.

Take a look at this method: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattributenodens.php

Comment: I see now that in fact the attributes ARE printed, but without the namespace... so I changed my question...